# global-ignores ignores either directories or files

Tags: svn, ignore, directory

I am putting a directory called PIPELINE under version control using subversion. The directory has certain folders such as blah12/Dataset which shouldn'be be versioned because they contain data which doesnt change. Also, because matlab code is ran in the working copies of this directory, it ends up filled with temp files and log files such as .DS_Store, or blah.m~, and finally there are just some file types that contain non-informative nonchaning info, such as *.fig.

In order to eliminate those data directiories and useless files from becoming versioned, I add global-ignore statements in the  [miscellaneous] part of my the hidden ~/.subversion/config file.

Under the [miscellany] portion I add

```
global-ignores = Dataset paradigms CSCs *.dll *.fig .DS_Store *~
```

Now the problem is that having file parts (such as *.dll *.fig .DS_Store *~) in the global-ignores string for some reason makes subversion ignore the ignore directory entries (such as Datasets and paradigms)...it detects and Ignores the file parts, but checks in the directories!!!!

WHY does this happen???

Comment: Are you ignoring `Dataset` or `Datasets` as a directory. You mentioned you want to ignore `Dataset`, but your ignore is plural, `Datasets`.

Comment: Does `Dataset` already exist as an element in your Subversion repository? If it does, it won't be ignored. I copied and pasted your `global-ignores` statement into my Subversion config. I use svn version 1.8.3 and I have no problems.

Comment: That was it! I guess the deal is you have to configure the global-ignores before importing anything. Add your fix as an answer, so i can mark the q solved.